# how to get the thumbnail image of an uploaded image in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, image, thumbnails

I uploaded an image and save it as thumbnail in the mongodb, but when I retrieve it to the app the thumbnail image is not showing. This is application.js

Here is my code

```
    var mongoose = require('mongoose');
    var thumbnailPluginLib = require('mongoose-thumbnail');
    var thumbnailPlugin = thumbnailPluginLib.thumbnailPlugin;

    var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

        enter code here

    var ApplicationSchema = new Schema({
        appName: String,
        appTempPath:String,
        userId : String,
        status : String,
        templateId: String,
        themeColor : String,

    });
    ApplicationSchema.plugin(thumbnailPlugin, {
      name: "appIcon"


    });

    var Application = mongoose.model('Application', ApplicationSchema);
```

This is my view.html

```
<a ui-sref="{{templateApp.target}}">
    <button class="panel panel-primary" title="App information">
    <img src="{{templateApp.image}}"></img>
        <div class="panel-heading">{{templateApp.title}}</div>
            <div class="panel-body">
              <div ng-show='!!templateApp.info'>


                  <hr/><span class="product__price highlight">
                {{templateApp.info}}</span>
              </div>
        </div>
  </button>
</a>
```

The image I upload might be big, but through mongoose-thumbnail it becomes a little icon. I need a little icon to appear in my appbox. The image is not appearing in my appBox. please give me an answer to this problem. The url is coming to the view from the database as in the inspect.

Comment: use ng-src instead of src

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using ng-src and not just src in your img

from the docs:

> Using Angular markup like {{hash}} in a src attribute doesn't work
>   right: The browser will fetch from the URL with the literal text
>   {{hash}} until Angular replaces the expression inside {{hash}}. The
>   ngSrc directive solves this problem.

**Edit:**
After seeing the image source(in the comments), it need to be cleared and only consists of http://....

Comment: Does templateApp.image get the right full path to the image?

Comment: yes. It does. In the inspect the url is visible nicely, but there is both the compressed url and the original url.

Comment: Can you paste what you are seeing?

Comment: It is too long to paste here but I'll remove some letters in the src. <img ng-src="{&quot;url&quot;:&quot;blob:http%3A//localhost%3A9000/af71289a-6fc5-4245-add3-1d68bcad04c7&quot;,&quot;compressed&quot;:{&quot;dataURL&quot;:&quot;data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgAAhmURs4FdTegFhoYz19oO+UudAaA1Zw553hKZjCaXSK2rbfQUEAlF9HADVFKhz9Brw0YerDKfohmXjVKoZmOjoVY4tsOppD8zFDIkPXKGPIMS2/ODjEOlLmihflQ/O2giY6OaS2LRkwyijZ6Cvhyjo6OieplKR//9k=&quot;}">

Comment: the source does not look right, it looks html encoded, you should clean this string and have only the http://localhost:9000/af71289a-6fc5-4245‌​-add3-1d68bcad04c7 part

Comment: I got it correct now. After compressing I sent only the url via the scope.   'appIcon': $scope.image.compressed.dataURL,                                                      Thanks anyway

Comment: I'll be happy if you could accept the answer, I will add the added solution